# rest php client unmarshalling exception

Tags: php, rest, exception

The task is to build a REST client in php, sending and recieving XML (weired, I know).

If I send something to the REST-api, I get an UnmarshallingException.

What does this mean?

Here is a part of my code:

```
public function createOrganisationUnit($kvcObject){
    try{
        $restclient = new RestClient(Environment::getConfiguration()['rest_url']);
        $response = $restclient->execute(
            RestClient::REQUEST_TYPE_POST,
            '/rest/organisations/'.self::getOurID().'/organisationunits',
            $kvcObject->xmlOrganisationUnit()
        );
        echo 'createOrg<br>';var_dump($response);echo'<br>';
        if ($response['http_code'] == 201){         //created, return new ID
            return substr($response['body'], strrpos($response['body'], "/"));
        }elseif($response['http_code'] == 400){     //allready there, return found ID
            return self::getOrganisationUnitsID($kvcObject->getOrganisationUnit()->getBsnr());
        }else{                                      // error, return false
            return false;
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        print_r( $e->getMessage() ) . PHP_EOL;
    }   
}
```

Where $kvcConnect->xmlOrganisationUnit() delivers the xml as string.
And self::getOurID() is working fine, delivers the suggested ID as Integer.

I do not use Symfony or any other frameworks.

Best regards
Johannes

Comment: Where is the code that produces this error?

Comment: @Morgoth: I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("your file"));
    AddRequest req = JAXB.unmarshal(inputStream, AddRequest.class);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This code may answer the question, but could you add some context to explain why it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that a sprint("%s", $post_data) inside my RestClass was the problem.